# retrieve data from activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app takes data from 4 EditTexts, puts them in an ArrayList and with a press of a button (using Intents) passes the data to second activity which then prints that data in 4 TextViews and has a button that returns me to first activity for next input. Is there any way of keeping all of my input data so I can show everything I've inputted in a TextView or Toast message?

Comment: can you please explain your question in detail? "Is there any way of keeping all of my input data so I can show everything I've inputted in a TextView or Toast message?" This is vague.. do you mean storing the data in Activity 1 or 2? or you mean to store aggregated data?

Comment: i think he did passing between values between objects. he trying to save a whole session data somewhere

Comment: Sorry about that, I'd like my app to save the data in second activity which will then (with a press of a button) display everything inputted in a Toast message or a TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your first Activity is A and second activity is B

so in the A activity's button press you can call the 2nd activity using following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
String input1 = txt1.getText().toString();
String input2 = txt2.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("key1", input1 );
intent.putExtra("key2", input2 );
startActivity(intent);
```

From the B activity you can access these values using following code

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String input1 = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
String input2 = intent.getStringExtra("key2");
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can. you can pass your data to second activity like this.

```
Intent intent1= new Intent(first.this, second.class);
                        Bundle bundle1=new Bundle();
                        bundle1.putString("data", et1.getText().toString());
                        intent1.putExtras(bundle1);
                        startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
```

or you can restore them in a temporary database.